# Bing Geo Migration query bug

Tags: geolocation, linkedin-api, bing

I am trying to migrate our LinkedIn API logic from legacy locations to Bing geo location. However, when i follow the [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/advertising-targeting/bing-geo-migration-guide) a request fails. The request is as follows:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adTargetingEntities?q=urns&queryVersion=QUERY_USES_URNS&urns=List(urn%3Ali%3Astate%3A%28urn%3Ali%3Acountry%3Aus%2CCA%29,urn%3Ali%3Aregion%3A82)&locale=(language:en,country:US)
```

Which is actually an [example query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/advertising-targeting/bing-geo-migration-guide#get-the-name-of-the-new-bing-geo-location-values) from the guide. It fails with a code `403 Forbidden: Unpermitted fields present in PARAMETER: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/locale]`. When i try to remove the locale parameter, it casts an error of `400 Bad Request: Array parameter 'urns' value 'List(urn:li:state:(urn:li:country:us,CA),urn:li:region:82)' is invalid. Reason: Invalid URN syntax: Urn doesn't start with 'urn:'{...}`. This means that i can only query for one **urn** at a time, which is not what i want. How do i achieve the following:

1. Provide locale to the query
2. Query for multiple urns at a time

The curl command for the request is here:

`curl --location --request GET 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adTargetingEntities?q=urns&queryVersion=QUERY_USES_URNS&urns=List(urn%3Ali%3Astate%3A%28urn%3Ali%3Acountry%3Aus%2CCA%29,urn%3Ali%3Aregion%3A82)' \ --header 'Authorization: Bearer {AUTH}' \`

Comment: Hey @Soren have you reached out to your customer rep / partner engineering rep by chance?

Also can you provide a curl command to replicate the above.

Comment: Hey. Yes I have, but we can't seem to figure it out. I have added the curl command to the post.

Comment: hey @Søren Gade -- sorry not sure why tagging is not working. 
I think perhaps the addition of this param may solve your issue as the syntax between Version 1 and 2 is different for many things including lists.

 `-H X-RestLi-Protocol-Version:2.0.0` 

I forget this quite a lot and get frustrated :-)